# HoloLens2 buttons get sticky when TextWriter is added

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm developing a quiz-style app for HoloLens2 using Unity 2019.4.20f1 (for some reason, it has to be this version of Unity). The app randomly sets one of pooled questions one after another, and users answer the question by pressing one of the option buttons.

I'm trying to keep the track of the given question, selected answer, the spared time, etc with TextWriter logging the data in csv file. But when I add it to the script, the buttons on HoloLens2 get "sticky" (hand mesh stuck on the touched button for a bit). I wondered how I could make the buttons work smoothly with TextWriter?

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class QuizUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private QuizManager quizManager;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject startButton;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject imageHolder;
    [SerializeField] private Image questionImage;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject questionModel;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject optionHolder;
    [SerializeField] private List<GameObject> options;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject endInfo;

    private Question question;
    private bool answered = false;
    private GameObject clone;
    public Stopwatch stopwatch;
    public bool val;
    string filename = "";
    private string clickedBtn;

    private void Awake()
    {
        imageHolder.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        optionHolder.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        endInfo.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        filename = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/PurdueLogfile.csv";
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        var interactable = startButton.GetComponent<Interactable>();
        interactable.OnClick.AddListener(() => Prepare());
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        var interactable = startButton.GetComponent<Interactable>();
        interactable.OnClick.RemoveListener(() => Prepare());
    }

    private void Prepare()
    {
        startButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        imageHolder.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        optionHolder.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        
        //add the listner to all the buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < options.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject localBtn = options[i];
            var interactable = options[i].GetComponent<Interactable>();
            interactable.OnClick.AddListener(() => OnClick(localBtn));
        }

        //log start time
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filename, true);
        tw.WriteLine("[" + System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff") + "]" + "," + "Start");
        tw.Close();
        
        quizManager.StartGame();
        
    }

    public void SetQuestion(Question question)
    {
        //set the question
        this.question = question;
        //check for questionType
        switch (question.questionType)
        {
            case QuestionType.IMAGE:
                questionImage.transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                questionImage.transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);    //activate image holder
                questionModel.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                questionImage.sprite = question.questionImg;           //set the image sprite
                break;

            case QuestionType.MODEL:
                questionImage.transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                questionImage.transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                questionModel.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                clone = Instantiate(question.questionMdl, new Vector3(0, -0.15f, 0.8f), Quaternion.Euler (0f, -90f, 0f)) as GameObject;
                clone.transform.SetParent(questionModel.transform);
                break;
        }

        //assign options to respective option buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < options.Count; i++)
        {
            options[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>().text = question.options[i];
        }

        answered = false;

        //stopwatch to start
        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
    }

    public void OnClick(GameObject btn)
    {
        if (!answered)
        {
            answered = true;
            bool val = quizManager.Answer(btn.name);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(btn.name);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(val);
            clickedBtn = btn.name;

            //stopwatch to stop
            stopwatch.Stop();   
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(stopwatch.Elapsed);

            //log answers
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filename, true);
            tw.WriteLine("[" + System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff") + "]" + "," + quizManager.selectedQuestion.questionID + "," + quizManager.selectedQuestion.questionType + "," + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "," + val + "," + clickedBtn);
            tw.Close();

            //destroy 3D models
            DestroyImmediate(clone, true);
        }
    }

    public void EndGame()
    {
        imageHolder.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        optionHolder.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        endInfo.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

`

I'd appreciate it if someone could help. Thank you in advance :)

I tried using coroutine, but it only delays the point where the button gets sticky. Also, the time before generating the next question is limited, so I can delay only so much...

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple test and didn't reproduce your issue. But I noticed that **TextWriter** is thread-unsafe, you can try its synchronized method - **[TextWriter.Synchronized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter?view=net-7.0#remarks)**. Also, you cannot access the documents folder on UWP by default, please refer to [File access permissions - UWP applications | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) for file access permissions on UWP. And you can refer [Create, write, and read a file - UWP applications | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files) for how to read and write files on UWP.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried TextWriter.Synchronized, but unfortunately it didn't seem to change the stickiness of the buttons. I'm trying to change where the file is stored, but I'm getting error CS0246 (namespace "Windows" could not be found). What could I do? (Sorry, I'm new to all this coding stuff tbh!)

Comment: Has the WinRT API related code been placed under **ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT**? Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/using-the-windows-namespace-with-unity-apps-for-hololens#conditionally-include-winrt-api-calls.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT worked. But because creating and writing file uses 'await' (therefore async) it doesn't let me destroy models from the previous question. I also don't have access to Device Portal due to the computer setting by the organisation. How could I access to the stored file on HoloLens2?

Comment: You can access the created files through the **File Explorer** app on your HoloLens device.